# Can a .s file be executed directly?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64

I'm looking for an explanation of why I can't use a `.s` file directly.

I am trying to learn Assembly language on X86_64, and this gives me assembly code:

```
gcc -S sample.c
```

Why can't I run it directly using `nasm`?

I renamed `sample.s` to `sample.asm` and tried to do this:

```
 nasm -f elf -l sample.lst  sample.asm
```

But it gives me an error (Will post if needed). I thought that the intermediate file is in assembly code. Please clarify.

Comment: maybe it is not for win32 or win64 directly. maybe you chould put .model flat or something like that at beginning

Comment: Um, [the same kind of question has just been asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11533478/968261).

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze.. thanks. I will read and come back if any issue. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem if probably that the assembly from GCC and the one used by nasm is not using the same syntax!

GCC uses so-called AT&T syntax while nasm uses the standard Intel syntax. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax for a little information about the differences.

Comment: You might be able to use llvm-mc to convert from one to the other (no promise)